# Installing Apriltag through pip

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-wheel, apriltags

I have tried to pip install apriltag on multiple laptops, both windows and mac, but I keep getting the error

ERROR: Failed building wheel for apriltags

I have 'wheel' and opencv (opencv-contrib-python) and cmake installed already.

I know there are several very similar posts but the solutions are mostly to install pupil_apriltags instead. I need to use this specific library though, because I'm running a written code based on it.

Here's the output from my terminal:

```
C:\Users\vas7805>pip install apriltags
Collecting apriltags
  Downloading apriltags-0.0.7.tar.gz (12.6 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 12.6/12.6 MB 29.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: apriltags
  Building wheel for apriltags (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [141 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      copying python\apriltag.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      running build_ext
      C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\setup.py:30: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        cmake_version = LooseVersion(re.search(r'version\s*([\d.]+)', out.decode()).group(1))
      -- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
      CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:1 (project):
        cmake_minimum_required() should be called prior to this top-level project()
        call.  Please see the cmake-commands(7) manual for usage documentation of
        both commands.
      This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

      -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
      -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.32.31329.0
      -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.32.31329.0
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
      CMake Error at C:/Users/vas7805/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
        The C compiler

          "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

        is not able to compile a simple test program.

        It fails with the following output:

          Change Dir: C:/Users/vas7805/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-xs6no0kz/apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-311/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-e2mrsv

          Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe cmTC_33837.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 /v:n && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.2.1+52cd2da31 for .NET Framework
          Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

          Build started 7/6/2023 1:34:04 PM.
          Project "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
          PrepareForBuild:
            Creating directory "cmTC_33837.dir\Debug\".
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(524,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
            Creating directory "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\Debug\".
            Creating directory "cmTC_33837.dir\Debug\cmTC_33837.tlog\".
          InitializeBuildStatus:
            Creating "cmTC_33837.dir\Debug\cmTC_33837.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
          ClCompile:
            C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_33837.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_33837.dir\Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W3 /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\testCCompiler.c"
            Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.32.31329 for x64
            testCCompiler.c
            Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
            cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_33837.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_33837.dir\Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W3 /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\testCCompiler.c"
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "CL.exe" could not be run. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.dir\Debug\cmTC_33837.tlog'. [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit() [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern) [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TrackedDependencies.ExpandWildcards(ITaskItem[] expand) [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.CanonicalTrackedOutputFiles.InternalConstruct(ITask ownerTask, ITaskItem[] tlogFiles, Boolean constructOutputsFromTLogs) [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL.PostExecuteTool(Int32 exitCode) [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          Done Building Project "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

          Build FAILED.

          "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
          (PrepareForBuild target) ->
            C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(524,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]


          "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
          (ClCompile target) ->
            C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "CL.exe" could not be run. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.dir\Debug\cmTC_33837.tlog'. [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit() [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern) [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TrackedDependencies.ExpandWildcards(ITaskItem[] expand) [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.CanonicalTrackedOutputFiles.InternalConstruct(ITask ownerTask, ITaskItem[] tlogFiles, Boolean constructOutputsFromTLogs) [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL.PostExecuteTool(Int32 exitCode) [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(700,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-e2mrsv\cmTC_33837.vcxproj]

              1 Warning(s)
              1 Error(s)

          Time Elapsed 00:00:00.24





        CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\setup.py", line 62, in <module>
          setup(
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 968, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 343, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 132, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\setup.py", line 35, in run
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xs6no0kz\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\setup.py", line 59, in build_extension
          subprocess.check_call(['cmake', ext.sourcedir] + cmake_args, cwd=self.build_temp, env=env)
        File "C:\Users\vas7805\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\vas7805\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xs6no0kz\\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\vas7805\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xs6no0kz\\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\vas7805\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\vas7805\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xs6no0kz\\apriltags_65a44e3a6ec340638e82da3986bfe0e9\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for apriltags
  Running setup.py clean for apriltags
Failed to build apriltags
ERROR: Could not build wheels for apriltags, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: make sure you got the name of the package right. might be a different package. PyPI is not curated.